# Remix code got deleted automatically

Tags: solidity, remix

I created a small smart contract on Remix IDE. Compiler passed the contract without error. However, when I switch back to my contract after opening another contract file in remix, the solidity code got vanished. I am not getting what the issue is. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You should contact the developers.

Comment: Remix stores the contract source in the browser local storage, if for some reason it gets corrupted you might lose them. It works well most of the time, even it survived browser crashes. It happened only once I lost files because a remix update changed things around and I deleted my files without realizing it. If the contracts are important for you make sure to have backups, files are stored only in your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved when I deleted the artifacts folder from the remix and recompiled the code once again.